# Arraylist extract values and update

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists. I am using one arraylist as a key to store values.

In nutshell, my code is as below.

```
    for(int i=0;i<transactionid.size(); i++)
    {
        if(transactionid.get(i).equals(transactionnumber))
        {
            transactionvalue.set(i, transactionvalues);
        }
    }
```

In the above program snippet, **transactionid** is used to store my key values. If there is a match in the key value, I am updating the arraylist **transactionvalue**.

So far so good. But now, I want to update another arraylist **diskitemvalues** based on the above two arraylist values.  The update is something like below.

```
for(int i=0;i<transactionid.size(); i++)
{
    if(transactionid.get(i).equals(transactionnumber))
    {
    try
    {
        /* Open file to read contents*/
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
           /* Get the values of transactionvalue arraylist and update them. */
           /* The transactionvalue arraylist contains values like {X Y}     */
           /* So my update in the diskitemvalues arraylist 
              should be X = so & so Y = so & so based on file               */
```

I have to navigate to the particular value in the **transactionid** arraylist and for that particular key, I have to find out the corresponding values in the **transactionvalue** arraylist and update the **diskitemvalues** arraylist for all values present in the **transactionvalue** arraylist.

Example:

Transactionid transactionvalue
 1                 X Y

2                 M N

For transactionid = 2, my diskitemvalues [2] should have M = so & so and N = so & so from the input file. If it is transactionid = 1, my diskitemvalues[1] should have X = so & so and Y = so & so from the input file.

Comment: I don't get it, if you find a transaction id, you replace the trasaction id with transaction values? Then you loose what you call the transaction id. Sound like you should be using a map instead of a list.

Comment: Mind if I ask why are you using two ArrayLists, when a HashMap or a Map in general might make it easier to work with.

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but I strongly suggest using a map (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to keep your keys and values together.

Comment: I started using arraylist and almost finished what I wanted to do. However, in the future I will use Hashmap or a Map.